# My javascript is not being executed in my safari browser

Tags: javascript

I am using Safari and the Atom text editor. I have a basic html file with javascript code between script tags. However when I click on the folder that the code is saved in none of my javascript code is working in the browser, nor my Chrome browser. I double checked that javascript was enabled and that there were no plug-ins causing it to not run. I am trying to make an alert if the user's value is 0 and substitute the  for the value entered into the text box once the "Click Me" button is clicked.

When I use an "onload...alert" attribute in the body element , the javascript worked perfectly.

Is it the text-editor? My code? Any ideas?

My code is below:

```js
function substitute() {
  var myValue = document.getElementById('myTextBox').value;
  if (myValue.length == 0) {
    alert ('Enter a Real Value');
    return;
  }

  var myTitle = document.getElementById('title');
  myTitle.innerHTML=myValue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Example</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1 id="title">Javascript Example</h1>
<form>
<input type="text" id="myTextBox"/>
<input type="submit" value="Click Me" onclick="substitute"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, taking away the <form> element doesn't change anything.

Comment: Where is your Javascript code? How is the browser supposed to find it?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, are you linking the JS file anywhere in your html? At the end of your body tag, you should add something like this:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Also, 'substitute' is a function so it should be 'substitute()'